# the_author() not working outside the loop

Tags: php, author, include

I have the following code on index.php and I want to include this line of code (bellow) to display author info on top of the loop.

```
 <?php include 'author-top.php'; ?><!--author-->
```

I want it to display right after the header as shows here

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!--This is where I want my author div to display-->
<?php include 'author-top.php'; ?><!--author-->
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <div id="content" class="site-content-home" role="main">                
        <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                  <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

                  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'home' );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php spun_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php elseif ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

This is what I get:
http://gyazo.com/4154248fa37c84f9cb8f52871f186723.png

When I try to use the same 'php include' somewhere else at the bottom of the index.php code everything seems to work well. The problem is I need it on the top so it shows on the top on the small screens.

Is it anything I'm doing wrong? or it is that wordpress doesnt allow to do use 'php includes' in there and if so why not.

This is the content inside author-top.php

```
<!-- get author bio **RAUL -->
<!-- This is the author info displayed at the top of each page -->
<div id="author-bio">
    <div class="author-image"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '80' ); ?></div>
    <div class="author-txt">
        <h2 class="author-name" id="clickme"><?php the_author(); ?></h2>
        <p class="toggle author-description"><?php the_author_description(); ?></br>
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/raulmvicente"><img class="author-social" src="http://www.webleria.com/wp-content/themes/spun/images/linkedin_circle_color.png"></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/raulmvicente"><img class="author-social" src="http://www.webleria.com/wp-content/themes/spun/images/twitter_circle_color.png"></a>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/116575236589076788314?rel=author"><img class="author-social" src="http://www.webleria.com/wp-content/themes/spun/images/google_circle_color.png"></a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#clickme').click(function() { $( '.toggle' ).animate({ "height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle" }, "slow" )});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the content of `author-top.php`? It might rely on variables not available before the loop start.

Comment: Thanks toscho. Im not sure what you mean. I have added the code inside author-top.php to the question. I dont think there is any variable in there. Also I have to mention I have the same problem adding the author-top.php just after get_header()

Comment: What if you use `<?php get_template_part( 'author', 'top' ); ?>`?

Comment: Hi Mayeenul. I just tried and I got the same result. It doesnt display.

Comment: Where does the `author-top.php` file reside, in relation to the rest of the Theme files?

Comment: To test to see if the file is included at the top, you should look at the browser page source, not only what is displayed in the browser. In Firefox, right-click the browser page, then press `V`. In the new page, press `ctrl-f` and search for `get author bio`. If the comment is near the top of the page content, the file is included.

Comment: sir i try to show auther name on my post but I not able to show this I use <?php the_author(); ?>

Answer (score 9):

I will answer my own question here.

The reason the user information didn't display is because the php tags need the author ID when used outside the loop.

For instance the following tag:

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

Should be like this:

```
<?php the_author_meta('display_name', 1); ?>
```

[This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) is explain quite well here.

Now the code works just fine.

Comment: If you had better read the first comment by @toscho you would have solved the problem few minutes after publish question

Comment: Please **edit your question** to make the question title and content more accurately reflect the actual issue/problem being solved.

Comment: @G.M. I didn't get the meaning in the first comment by toscho. I'm not too familiar with wordpress yet and the answer looked to technical but yeah it was correct.

Comment: @ChipBennett I have already changed the title.

Comment: @BradDaltron answered it and then you just copied that. You should acept his answer as the correct one though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a single page you can just use the `post_author`'s id. You can write: `the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author );` that worked just fine for me. That way you don't have to hard code the id.

Answer (score 1):

A user ID must be specified if used outside The Loop.

Try this in author-top.php

```
<?php get_the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); ?>
```

Must include the user ID.

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta